# Git Large File Storage - remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size

Tags: ios, git, github, git-lfs

I am using Git Large File Storage and I have 50 GB of Git LFS Data storage (and bandwidth) available on GitHub.

I would like to push multiple tar files, totaling 40 GB. The largest of the files is 30 GB.

On my mac, I did the commands:

```
git lfs track "*.tar"
git add .gitattributes
```

Both of these were successful. However, when I do:

```
git add .
git commit -am "add big files"
git push origin master
```

The third command fails with the following output:

```
work@x86_64-apple-darwin13 XX-XXX-s20 % git add . --verbose
add '.DS_Store'
add 'Archive/.DS_Store'
add 'Archive/Kaggle/.DS_Store'
add 'Archive/Kaggle/1p2/XX-XXX-1p2.zip'
add 'Archive/Kaggle/1p2/solution.csv'
add 'Archive/Kaggle/2p2/XX-XXX-2p2.zip'
add 'Archive/Kaggle/2p2/2p2-c-solution.csv'
add 'Archive/Kaggle/2p2/2p2-v-solution.csv'
add 'Archive/Kaggle/3p2/XX-XXX-3p2.zip'
add 'Archive/Kaggle/3p2/3p2-solution.csv'
add 'Archive/Kaggle/4p2/XX-XXX-4p2.zip'
add 'Archive/Kaggle/4p2/p2-solution.csv'

work@x86_64-apple-darwin13 XX-XXX-s20 % git commit -am "add Kaggle data"
[master bb327ea] add Kaggle data
 12 files changed, 1129208 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .DS_Store
 create mode 100644 Archive/.DS_Store
 create mode 100644 Archive/Kaggle/.DS_Store
 create mode 100644 Archive/Kaggle/1p2/XX-XXX-1p2.zip
 create mode 100644 Archive/Kaggle/1p2/1p2-solution.csv
 create mode 100644 Archive/Kaggle/2p2/XX-XXX-2p2.zip
 create mode 100644 Archive/Kaggle/2p2/2p2-c-solution.csv
 create mode 100644 Archive/Kaggle/2p2/2p2-v-solution.csv
 create mode 100644 Archive/Kaggle/3p2/XX-XXX-3p2.zip
 create mode 100644 Archive/Kaggle/3p2/3p2-solution.csv
 create mode 100644 Archive/Kaggle/4p2/XX-XXX-4p2.zip
 create mode 100644 Archive/Kaggle/4p2/4p2-solution.csv

work@x86_64-apple-darwin13 XX-XXX-s20 % git push origin master
Enumerating objects: 22, done.
Counting objects: 100% (22/22), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly1.59 MiB/s   
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Why am I unable to upload these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, if anybody used large file storage on free account then you can use only one time. and you can use 1GB free (remembered only onetime)

and if you used in purchased account then no need to use large file storage. you can directly push

```
git lfs track "*.tar"
git add .gitattributes
Both of these were successful. However, when I do:

git add .
git commit -am "add big files"
git push origin master
```

your cmd is ok remembered it if you use different 2 type then you should give 
type like my file .tar, .a, .b. .c then give

```
git lfs track "*.tar"
git lfs track "*.a"
git lfs track "*.b"
git lfs track "*.c"
```

Comment: I am using a pro account, and you are right -- I also need to specify the zip files.